# subset problem (set theory)

Tags: reference-request, elementary-set-theory

$$A \subseteq B \subseteq C$$
There's $k$ amount of elements in set $A$ and $t$ amount of elements in set $C$.
What is the maximum amount of possible $B$ sets available?
$k$ and $t$ are natural numbers.

Comment: What is your thinking on this? Have you tries any simple examples to see what happens?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Since $A \subseteq B$, $k$ elements of $B$ are fixed. Each of the remaining $t-k$ elements of $C$ independently $\in B$ or $\notin B$.

> $A \subseteq B$ means that all $k$ elements $A$ are also elements of $B$. There remains $t-k$ elements of $C$ each of which may or may not belong to $B$. So we have 2 possibilities (either $\in B$ or $\notin B$) for each of these $t-k$ elements. Hence there are $2^{t-k}$ possible $B$'s available.

Comment: It is my $27^{th}$ day on Math.SE and I still do not understand: Why am I getting downvotes for CORRECT answers?

Comment: One can only guess. A couple of possibilities: the downvoter was confused and simply didn’t understand the answer; the downvoter doesn’t like hints. It’s very annoying, but there’s nothing to be done about it. As far as I’m concerned it’s a fine answer (+1).

Comment: I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with writing the answer down in a proper way. I understand the concept but lack the skill to write it down...

Comment: @vilbur, I added the solution to the answer.