# area of shaded region in circle

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

> **Solution** : $\angle O = \angle D = \theta$ (corresponding angles)
>
> Also we can use area of sector formula

After that, I have no idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The area of the shaded region $CDB$ is equal to the area of the sector $AOB$ minus the  sum of the areas of the sector $AOC$ and the triangle $\Delta OCD$:

$$A(CDB) = A(AOB) - A(AOC) - A(\Delta OCD)$$

The area of the sector $AOB$ is simply $(1/2) R^2 \theta$.

Now, to find the other areas, we need $\beta=\angle COD$.  We find this using the law of sines for the angle $\alpha = \angle OCD$:

$$\frac{\sin{(\pi-\theta)}}{R}=\frac{\sin{\alpha}}{\ell}$$

Combining this with $\alpha+\beta+(\pi-\theta)=\pi$ from $\Delta OCD$, we get that

$$\beta = \theta-\arcsin{\left (\frac{\ell }{R}\sin{\theta}\right )}$$

In terms of $\beta$, $A(AOC)=(1/2) R^2 (\theta-\beta)$ and $A(\Delta OCD)=(1/2) R \ell \sin{\beta}$.  Putting this all together, I get

$$A(CDB) = \frac12 R^2 \left [ \theta-\arcsin{\left (\frac{\ell }{R}\sin{\theta}\right )}\right] +\frac14 \ell^2 \sin{2 \theta} - \frac12 \ell \sin{\theta} \sqrt{R^2-\ell^2 \sin^2{\theta}}$$

Comment: thanks a lot. now it is much clear to me

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The area of the shaded region equals the area of the sector $OCB$ minus the area of the triangle $OCD$.

Comment: What is the formula for area of triangle ?

Comment: how can you find area of  sector OCB as <BOC not given

Comment: In the triangle $OCD$ the angle $\angle ODC$ and the sides $OC$ and $OD$ are known. You can find $\angle BOC$.

Comment: Once again, I would like to ask my question in the following comment:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/487176/subset-problem-set-theory/487179#comment1048551_487179